# Как сделать триггер правильно?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я не знаю как сделать так что бы когда перс стоял на триггере то тогда клавиша работала а когда не стоит не работала
вот скрипт

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class TpGGhaus : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int levelToLoad;

    public Vector3 position;
    public VectorValue playerStorage;

    if (Input.GetKeyUp("e"))
        {
            playerStorage.initialValue = position;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
        }

}
```

Просто у меня клавиша работает в любой точке карты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bool IsInTriger = false;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    IsInTriger = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) 
{
    IsInTriger = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if (IsInTriger && Input.GetKeyUp("e") ) {
        playerStorage.initialValue = position;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelToLoad);
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html

PS:

> OnTriggerStay is called almost all the frames for
> every Collider other that is touching the trigger.The function is on
> the physics timer so  **IT WON'T NECESSARILY RUN EVERY FRAME.** - поэтому не подходит

Comment: Извини за вопрос но у меня unity выдает ошибку The field 'TpGGhaus.IsInTriger' is assigned but its value is never used в переводе Поле «TpGGhaus.IsInTriger» назначено, но его значение никогда не используется

Comment: обновил ответ ....

Comment: Я капец тупой но у меня при запуске игры вылазит ошибки всех зданий например https://imgur.com/a/F9vmlJg и все равно не работает клавиша

Comment: слушай, я за тебя очень рад, но тебе нужно начать с азов программирования в консоли, а уже потом лезть в что-то сложнее вроде юнити. Потому что ты явно не понимаешь как пользоваться шарпом в принципе.... Или ты учишь азы или ты будешь просить других писать код вместо тебя и ты ничего не научишся в принципе. Это сервис ПОМОЩИ в написании кода, а сервис написания кода вместо тебя называется "фриланс-биржа". Без обид, но сначала освой язык программирования на базовом уровне

Comment: это буквально попытка лезть в высшую математику не освоив умножения. Ну напишу я код вместо тебя от и до - дальше ты сюда прийдешь что бы кто-то написал второй код вместо тебя. И так по кругу. Это так не работает. Освой азы

Comment: Так это понятно просто я всегда брал код из ютуба там объясняли и так я учил код а урока на эту тему нет

Comment: Понял можно же сделать через OnTriggerStay

Comment: Огромное спасибо я понял как это делать